# Most used date query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I'm using SQL Server. How can I query all records for February 2018 only from my table? I'm looking for the most used date query. Then there should be the query that I can easily change this date.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would recommend you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) in order that you can write good quality questions and have people assist you. In this particular case please include a [mre] i.e. a small set of sample data, the expected results for the sample data, the research into option you have done, and the attempt you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `date` column or the like:

```
select *
from mytable
where mydate >= '20180201' and mydate < '20180301'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. So how can I make this date format parametric?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTableHere
WHERE YourDateColumn >= '20180201' AND YourDateColumn < '20180301'
```

Basically just use the normal `>=` and `<` operators, and the **ISO-8601** format date string literals to get anything from Feb 1, but *before* March 1, 2018.

This is of course **assuming** that `YourDateColumn` really is of `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` datatype - which it really ought to be!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. So how can I make this date format parametric?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYDATECOLUMN LIKE '2018-02%'
```

You could also use LIKE.

If your dates are saved as 2018-02-01 the above query will work.

If your dates are saved as 20180201 the answer of the others will work or use LIKE '201802%'

Comment: `LIKE` in SQL Server **doesn't work** on  `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` column - which this really ought to be!

Comment: @marc_s `LIKE` **does** work in `DATETIME2` I've used it a lot in my environment. I thought it would also work in `DATETIME` and `DATE` so if it doesn't then it's my mistake.